# Как узнать список запущенных процессов в Ubuntu?

Tags: linux

Как узнать список запущенных процессов в Ubuntu?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Для этого надо открыть терминал и выполнить команду

```
ps -la // Для получения основных сведений о процессах, запущенных текущем пользователем
ps -ela  // Для всех пользователей 
ps -a  // Базовая информация для текущего пользователя
```

Answer (score 7):

```
top
```

В нем жмем k (kill), вводим номер процесса, жмем 9 (по-любому кильнуть)

```
ps ax | grep 'ищем процесс по куску имени'
```

Список процессов

```
kill PID[ PID2 PID3]
```

Киляем процесс по его id

```
killall PIDNAME
```

Киляем все процессы по имени

Comment: top
ps -ax 

Если через ltsp работаешь, то сначала ltsp-localapps xterm
А потом уже используй команды, описанные выше

Answer (score 5):

а для наблюдения за процессами в реальном времени лучше использовать htop

Answer (score 4):

```
ps aux
```

и можно их килять по PID.

```
kill {process PID}
```

Comment: kill -9 PID

Answer (score 4):

А если нужно из программы на С/С++, то либо анализировать директорию /proc, либо использовать библиотеку libproc

Answer (score 4):

```
pstree
```

Выводит красивенькое дерево. Выглядит примерно так:

```
init─┬─bash───onlineconf-upda
 ├─bash───pinger-client
 ├─crond
 ├─4*[cronolog]
 ├─dbus-daemon
 ├─httpd───6*[httpd]
 ├─kthreadd/106─┬─khelper/106
 │              └─nfsiod/106
```

Answer (score 1):

ps -e

Полезнее всего