# Ошибка Apache Tomcat при запуске проекта maven

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, netbeans

Здравствуйте. При запуске Maven-проекта ошибка в "Не удалось запустить Tomcat".
Вот что в самом сервере:

```
java.util.logging.ErrorManager: 4
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0/logs/catalina.2018-02-06.log (Permission denied)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
at org.apache.juli.FileHandler.openWriter(FileHandler.java:504)
at org.apache.juli.FileHandler.<init>(FileHandler.java:176)
at org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.<init>(AsyncFileHandler.java:75)
at org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.<init>(AsyncFileHandler.java:67)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
at org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager.readConfiguration(ClassLoaderLogManager.java:562)
at org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager.readConfiguration(ClassLoaderLogManager.java:505)
at org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager.readConfiguration(ClassLoaderLogManager.java:309)
at java.util.logging.LogManager$3.run(LogManager.java:399)
at java.util.logging.LogManager$3.run(LogManager.java:396)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.util.logging.LogManager.readPrimordialConfiguration(LogManager.java:396)
at java.util.logging.LogManager.access$800(LogManager.java:145)
at java.util.logging.LogManager$2.run(LogManager.java:345)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.util.logging.LogManager.ensureLogManagerInitialized(LogManager.java:338)
at java.util.logging.LogManager.getLogManager(LogManager.java:378)
at java.util.logging.Logger.demandLogger(Logger.java:448)
at java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:502)
at org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.<init>(DirectJDKLog.java:68)
at org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.getInstance(DirectJDKLog.java:188)
at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.getInstance(LogFactory.java:115)
at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.getInstance(LogFactory.java:137)
at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:188)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.<clinit>(Bootstrap.java:52)
java.util.logging.ErrorManager: 4
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0/logs/localhost.2018-02-06.log (Permission denied)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
at org.apache.juli.FileHandler.openWriter(FileHandler.java:504)
at org.apache.juli.FileHandler.<init>(FileHandler.java:176)
at org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.<init>(AsyncFileHandler.java:75)
at org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.<init>(AsyncFileHandler.java:67)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
at org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager.readConfiguration(ClassLoaderLogManager.java:562)
at org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager.readConfiguration(ClassLoaderLogManager.java:505)
at org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager.readConfiguration(ClassLoaderLogManager.java:309)
at java.util.logging.LogManager$3.run(LogManager.java:399)
at java.util.logging.LogManager$3.run(LogManager.java:396)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.util.logging.LogManager.readPrimordialConfiguration(LogManager.java:396)
at java.util.logging.LogManager.access$800(LogManager.java:145)
at java.util.logging.LogManager$2.run(LogManager.java:345)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.util.logging.LogManager.ensureLogManagerInitialized(LogManager.java:338)
at java.util.logging.LogManager.getLogManager(LogManager.java:378)
at java.util.logging.Logger.demandLogger(Logger.java:448)
at java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:502)
at org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.<init>(DirectJDKLog.java:68)
at org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.getInstance(DirectJDKLog.java:188)
at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.getInstance(LogFactory.java:115)
at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.getInstance(LogFactory.java:137)
at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:188)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.<clinit>(Bootstrap.java:52)
java.util.logging.ErrorManager: 4
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0/logs/manager.2018-02-06.log (Permission denied)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
at org.apache.juli.FileHandler.openWriter(FileHandler.java:504)
at org.apache.juli.FileHandler.<init>(FileHandler.java:176)
at org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.<init>(AsyncFileHandler.java:75)
at org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.<init>(AsyncFileHandler.java:67)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
at org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager.readConfiguration(ClassLoaderLogManager.java:562)
at org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager.readConfiguration(ClassLoaderLogManager.java:505)
at org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager.readConfiguration(ClassLoaderLogManager.java:309)
at java.util.logging.LogManager$3.run(LogManager.java:399)
at java.util.logging.LogManager$3.run(LogManager.java:396)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.util.logging.LogManager.readPrimordialConfiguration(LogManager.java:396)
at java.util.logging.LogManager.access$800(LogManager.java:145)
at java.util.logging.LogManager$2.run(LogManager.java:345)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.util.logging.LogManager.ensureLogManagerInitialized(LogManager.java:338)
at java.util.logging.LogManager.getLogManager(LogManager.java:378)
at java.util.logging.Logger.demandLogger(Logger.java:448)
at java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:502)
at org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.<init>(DirectJDKLog.java:68)
at org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.getInstance(DirectJDKLog.java:188)
at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.getInstance(LogFactory.java:115)
at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.getInstance(LogFactory.java:137)
at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:188)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.<clinit>(Bootstrap.java:52)
java.util.logging.ErrorManager: 4
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0/logs/host-manager.2018-02-06.log (Permission denied)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
at org.apache.juli.FileHandler.openWriter(FileHandler.java:504)
at org.apache.juli.FileHandler.<init>(FileHandler.java:176)
at org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.<init>(AsyncFileHandler.java:75)
at org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.<init>(AsyncFileHandler.java:67)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
at org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager.readConfiguration(ClassLoaderLogManager.java:562)
at org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager.readConfiguration(ClassLoaderLogManager.java:505)
at org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager.readConfiguration(ClassLoaderLogManager.java:309)
at java.util.logging.LogManager$3.run(LogManager.java:399)
at java.util.logging.LogManager$3.run(LogManager.java:396)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.util.logging.LogManager.readPrimordialConfiguration(LogManager.java:396)
at java.util.logging.LogManager.access$800(LogManager.java:145)
at java.util.logging.LogManager$2.run(LogManager.java:345)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.util.logging.LogManager.ensureLogManagerInitialized(LogManager.java:338)
at java.util.logging.LogManager.getLogManager(LogManager.java:378)
at java.util.logging.Logger.demandLogger(Logger.java:448)
at java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:502)
at org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.<init>(DirectJDKLog.java:68)
at org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.getInstance(DirectJDKLog.java:188)
at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.getInstance(LogFactory.java:115)
at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.getInstance(LogFactory.java:137)
at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:188)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.<clinit>(Bootstrap.java:52)
06-Feb-2018 14:45:55.239 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.0.46
06-Feb-2018 14:45:55.244 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Aug 10 2017 10:10:31 UTC
06-Feb-2018 14:45:55.244 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         8.0.46.0
06-Feb-2018 14:45:55.245 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               FreeBSD
06-Feb-2018 14:45:55.245 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            11.1-RELEASE
06-Feb-2018 14:45:55.245 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
06-Feb-2018 14:45:55.245 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             /usr/local/openjdk8/jre
06-Feb-2018 14:45:55.246 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_152-b16
06-Feb-2018 14:45:55.246 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
06-Feb-2018 14:45:55.247 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         /usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0
06-Feb-2018 14:45:55.248 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         /usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0
06-Feb-2018 14:45:55.248 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0/conf/logging.properties
06-Feb-2018 14:45:55.249 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
06-Feb-2018 14:45:55.249 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=localhost|127.0.0.1|Oin.nm.eustrosoft.org
06-Feb-2018 14:45:55.250 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
06-Feb-2018 14:45:55.250 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
06-Feb-2018 14:45:55.251 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0/endorsed
06-Feb-2018 14:45:55.251 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0
06-Feb-2018 14:45:55.252 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0
06-Feb-2018 14:45:55.252 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0/temp
06-Feb-2018 14:45:55.253 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/local/openjdk8/jre/lib/amd64:/usr/local/openjdk8/jre/lib/i386::/usr/local/lib
06-Feb-2018 14:45:55.540 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
06-Feb-2018 14:45:55.564 SEVERE [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Failed to initialize end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
java.net.BindException: Address already in use
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:350)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:823)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:476)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.init(AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.java:120)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:960)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:568)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:871)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:581)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:604)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:310)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:484)
06-Feb-2018 14:45:55.567 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal Failed to initialize connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8080]]
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8080]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:568)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:871)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:581)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:604)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:310)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:484)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler initialization failed
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:962)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
... 12 more
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:350)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:823)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:476)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.init(AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.java:120)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:960)
... 13 more
06-Feb-2018 14:45:55.569 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
06-Feb-2018 14:45:55.573 SEVERE [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Failed to initialize end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
java.net.BindException: Address already in use
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:350)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:823)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:476)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:960)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:568)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:871)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:581)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:604)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:310)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:484)
06-Feb-2018 14:45:55.574 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal Failed to initialize connector [Connector[AJP/1.3-8009]]
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [Connector[AJP/1.3-8009]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:568)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:871)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:581)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:604)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:310)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:484)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler initialization failed
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:962)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
... 12 more
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:350)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:823)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:476)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:960)
... 13 more
06-Feb-2018 14:45:55.576 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 1687 ms
06-Feb-2018 14:45:55.678 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service Catalina
06-Feb-2018 14:45:55.679 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.46
06-Feb-2018 14:45:55.694 SEVERE [Catalina-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.open Failed to open access log file [/usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0/logs/localhost_access_log.2018-02-06.txt]
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0/logs/localhost_access_log.2018-02-06.txt (Permission denied)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.open(AccessLogValve.java:581)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.startInternal(AccessLogValve.java:611)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.startInternal(StandardPipeline.java:170)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:957)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:871)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
06-Feb-2018 14:45:55.700 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0/webapps/ROOT
06-Feb-2018 14:45:56.654 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.EmbeddedServletOptions.<init> The scratchDir you specified: /usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0/work/Catalina/localhost/ROOT is unusable.
06-Feb-2018 14:45:56.672 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0/webapps/ROOT has finished in 971 ms
06-Feb-2018 14:45:56.673 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0/webapps/docs
06-Feb-2018 14:45:56.741 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.EmbeddedServletOptions.<init> The scratchDir you specified: /usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0/work/Catalina/localhost/docs is unusable.
06-Feb-2018 14:45:56.744 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0/webapps/docs has finished in 70 ms
06-Feb-2018 14:45:56.745 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0/webapps/examples
06-Feb-2018 14:45:57.782 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.EmbeddedServletOptions.<init> The scratchDir you specified: /usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0/work/Catalina/localhost/examples is unusable.
06-Feb-2018 14:45:57.784 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0/webapps/examples has finished in 1,039 ms
06-Feb-2018 14:45:57.785 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0/webapps/host-manager
06-Feb-2018 14:45:57.874 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.EmbeddedServletOptions.<init> The scratchDir you specified: /usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0/work/Catalina/localhost/host-manager is unusable.
06-Feb-2018 14:45:57.877 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0/webapps/host-manager has finished in 92 ms
06-Feb-2018 14:45:57.878 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory /usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0/webapps/manager
06-Feb-2018 14:45:57.977 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.EmbeddedServletOptions.<init> The scratchDir you specified: /usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0/work/Catalina/localhost/manager is unusable.
06-Feb-2018 14:45:57.979 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory /usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0/webapps/manager has finished in 101 ms
06-Feb-2018 14:45:57.991 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 2415 ms
06-Feb-2018 14:45:57.994 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await StandardServer.await: create[localhost:8005]: 
java.net.BindException: Address already in use (Bind failed)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:387)
at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:375)
at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:237)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await(StandardServer.java:438)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.await(Catalina.java:718)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:664)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)
06-Feb-2018 14:45:58.001 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
06-Feb-2018 14:45:58.002 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
06-Feb-2018 14:45:58.003 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stopInternal Stopping service Catalina
06-Feb-2018 14:45:58.240 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
06-Feb-2018 14:45:58.241 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
06-Feb-2018 14:45:58.242 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
06-Feb-2018 14:45:58.242 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
```

Comment: а ты случаем не запускаешь томкат второй раз с указанием того же файла для логов и порта?

Comment: Я сменил порт, так как порт на кторором запускал имел ошибку "Порт занят"

Comment: @Zhuk `java.net.BindException: Address already in use` говорит о том, что "плохо" сменил

Comment: @Nikolay, спасибо и как тогда сменить не "плохо"?

Comment: проверьте сколько именно экземпляров у вас запущено

Comment: @Nikolay, как это проверить?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/261/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-ubuntu

Comment: у вас же unix ОС?

Comment: @Nikolay, Да, freebsd

Comment: вроде ничего такого в процессах не нашел

Comment: по всей видимости `Tomcat` хочет создать файл логов, но у него это не получается т.к. `Permission denied`, в общем разберитесь с правами

Comment: @ermak0ff, права админа

Comment: java.net.BindException: Address already in use (Bind failed), говорит о том, что ранее запущенный IDE процесс не остановлен.. два раза Ctrl+F2 останавливает запущенные процессы, два раза это если запускается с отладкой javaScript'ов (отдельный процесс стартует), а так достаточно одного нажатия, кстати при Exception в процессе запуска Tomcat - процесс также остается висеть - это видно в панели по состоянию кнопок (красная квадратная кнопка Stop активна)

Comment: @keekkenen, Ctrl+F2 для винды?

Comment: @Zhuk это стандартный хоткей IDEA.. везде должен работать одинаково, если не меняли

Comment: @keekkenen, на freebsd это работает как перключение между рабочим пространством